# Closing database connections on fatfree framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

I noticed an error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections` and I'm thinking it could be due to the sheer amount of connections to the database I've got.

IS there a way to close the database connection in fatfree framework to lower the likelyhood of this error popping up?

---

*edit:*

this is how I connect to an object:

```
$db=new DB\SQL($f3->get('db'),$f3->get('dbUserName'),$f3->get('dbPassword'));
```

would an unset($db) be enough, or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: To me, it looks like it's an issue in your code. I never had this issue with F3 and the default 150 max connections for my MySQL server. Since F3 uses PDO, the only way to close a connection is to destroy the PDO object. In this case it might work, if you destroy the \DB\SQL object.

Comment: I should mention that I have over 20 sites running on that server that are using a connection. There is also a cron job that each site is running that connects several times each minute. It would be helpful to be able to close the connection between between my wait procedures.

Comment: As mentioned, to close a PDO connection, destroy the object, which should normally happen automatically when the site finished loading. If you're running that many sites on a single server, it might be adviseable to increase the max connections.

Comment: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/rules-terms-of-service/mysql-connection-limits-processor-limits
   turns out it's a limit of 25 connections per instance with HG